# How to make Web forms custom validator to use Ajax CDN

Tags: asp.net, cdn

When using ASP.NET AJAX, you can point to an external CDN when declaring the script manager

for example

```
<asp:scriptmanager runat="server" enablecdn="true"></asp:scriptmanager>
```

However, I have noticed that if there is a user control on the same page which uses a custom validation, the framework still generates this code

```
/ScriptResource.axd?d=9yV7lSty3eIjRHuyQO6mUIbifRXho5yOz18Mb9LNzPDMVDZt5gucvycOn0YjgTb-p_rRW2V1ZDDrrpuaOC7nExHrA_4WmsL5gsOQ0m2syuuMp2VfpWep-II1V1zy1jHYfkvYfBRkGo_2LqqJh0Gung2&t=fffffffff11c85e0
```

which points to a local resource. I want this to point to the same CDN instead

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix/resolve this if it is of any help.
Basically I needed to disable '**AjaxFrameworkMode**' property of the ScriptManager as shown below

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableCdn="true" runat="server" AjaxFrameworkMode="Disabled"> </asp:ScriptManager>
```

> The AjaxFrameworkMode property adds two new modes to ScriptManager’s
>   behavior. Enabled (the default, and the same behavior as before),
>   Explicit (does not include any scripts by default but still assumes
>   Microsoft Ajax is to be utilized), and Disabled (does not include any
>   scripts by default and does not assume Microsoft Ajax will be used). For more details [read more...](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/asp-net-4-0-scriptmanager-improvements)